# avoid hyphen as minus in as.formula

Tags: r

I often need to convert large sets of variables from data frames into formulaic expressions. These variables sometimes have dashes/hyphens in them, and this gives `as.formula` trouble.

I am aware that I could just `gsub` these out of the data frame names, but that's undesirable as I need to map back to other annotation files which use the hyphens.

I have one workaround that leverages backticks (`` ` ``) and `paste0` below, but it feels clunky (i.e. is hard to read and may be less efficient than something in base that I've missed).

Is there a simpler expression that will get this done?

```
dat <- data.frame(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
names(dat) <- c("y", "x-1")

form <- as.formula(paste("y~", names(dat)[2]))
form #treats hyphen as minus
lm(form, data = dat) #error

# is this the only workaround?
form <- as.formula(paste("y~", paste0("`", names(dat)[2], "`")))
form
lm(form, data = dat)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `.`:

```
f <- y ~ .
lm(f, dat)
```

Subset the data.frame to only contain variables of interest.

Comment: That's really clever, and I can now avoid defining the formula outside the model call altogether with 

   `lm(y~., data=dat[,c("y", names(dat)[2])])`